# Error propagation with linear regression

Tags: regression, measurement-error, error-propagation

I'm trying to obtain an estimation of the uncertainty related to an analytical method:
my function is just a linear regression $f: y=ax+b+ \epsilon$ with $y_i=\frac{R_i}{C}$, both $R$ and $C$ are affected by a measured uncertainty, $s_R$ and $s_C$ respectively.

I want to calculate the total uncertainty with the generic formula for error propagation $$s_f^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Big[{\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\Big)s_{x_i}}\Big]^2$$
My $x_i$ are $R_i$ and $C$, so $$s^2_f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Big[{\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial R_i}\Big)s_{R_i}}\Big]^2+\Big[\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}\Big)s_{C}\Big]^2$$

with $$\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial R_i}\Big)^2= \Big(\frac{\partial a}{\partial R_i}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{\partial b}{\partial R_i}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial R_i}\Big)^2$$ and a similar expression for $\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}\Big)^2$.

The problem for which I need your help is the calculation of $\Big(\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial R_i}\Big)^2$.

Trying to solve the problem without taking into account the error term, lead me to the solution 
$$s^2_f=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{s^2_R+n^2\bar y^2 s_C^2}$$ so, an hyperbolic branch that, increasing $n$, approaches asymptotically to $0$. I think it has sense but it doesn't take into account the probabilistic part. What do you think about it?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are supposed to propagate the uncertainty in the fitted values of a and b (i.e., a-hat and b-hat), not the parameters a and b (which have no uncertainty) and the random error term from the formal model.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "total uncertainty"? Are you referring to some measure of variation in $y_i$ or in the estimated parameters $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$? What measure of variation are you using?